# Adding the value of two UILabels

Tags: swift

I'm making [an app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwWmo.png) where I want to add the value of two UILabels and show the result in a third UILabel.
I've tried doing `Int(totalOwed.text) = Int(numOfBoxesDelivered.text) - Int(numOfBoxesReturned.text)` but XCode throws an error telling me that the "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". How could I fix this?

Comment: `Int(totalOwed.text) =`, this is completely wrong. Think about it, what type is the result of the subtraction and what type does the label expect?

Comment: Isn't the result of the substraction an Int? My reasoning is that I'm converting both texts for numOfBoxesDelivered and numOfBoxesReturned into Integers, so the text for totalOwed should be converted to an Int as well. Right?

Comment: Well yes but you can’t convert a property from string to an int and assign a value to it. You are basically writing something like 0 = 5 - 3. Divide it into two statements, one for doing the subtraction and one for assigning the result of the subtraction to the label.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. However, if I try doing something like `let result = Int(numOfBoxesDelivered.text) - Int(numOfBoxesReturned.text)` and then `totalOwed.text = "\(result)"'`, Xcode still tells me that the type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texts values are optional try unwrapping them also `label.text` takes a String value you dont need to convert it! simply use this if you sure they have values

```
totalOwed.text = (Int(numOfBoxesDelivered.text!) - Int(numOfBoxesReturned.text!)).description
```

if not replace `!` with proper unwrapping methods i recommend reading optional in [swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) documentations

Comment: don't convert the 'totalOwed.text =' to integer look at my code again remove the Integer conversion from that you're using the setter and it takes string not integer copy my code and try again